# Initialize reference by typecasting the address of the variable

Tags: c++

What is this?
1)

```
CCamera &MyCamera = *(CCamera *)0xB6F028;
```

We get address of variable: 0xB6F028, typecast it to CCamera* and dereference.
And initialize CCamera reference. What? What its working?
By dereferencing we get a value of this address. And this value assign to reference?
2)

```
CPool<CVehicle, CHeli> *&CPools::ms_pVehiclePool =*(CPool<CVehicle, CHeli> **)0xB74494;
```

This we have CPool reference to pointer.
And we have address of pointer to begin of this class.
Next we typecast address of pointer to pointer to pointer to CPool like this:      (CPool**)0xB74494.
And then we dereference this and get value of 0xB74494. This value - its a pointer to begin CPool - this is an address of begin CPool in memory.
Well, this addresses in memory:  0xB74494 store value: 0xAddressOfCPool
What happend? Why we assign value of var to reference to pointer again?
We again assign a value of var.

How it works?

[image]

Comment: This trick maybe causes Undefined Behavior (UB), but im intrested!
And maybe we have a book which describe this tricks? Please let me know

Comment: `(CCamera *)` is an Explicit Type Conversion. This is pretty much the word of God to the compiler. No matter how stupid what ever you're about to do really is, the compiler will allow it, no questions asked. This means that if you don't have a valid `CCamera` at 0xB6F028, you will have UB up the <expletive deleted> as soon as you try to use that reference.

Comment: Usually you do this sort of thing in very low-level programming where you are directly interfacing with hardware. There's no way for the compiler to know you really have an accessible device at that address, but since you read the manual for the device you know it's there and can force the compiler to accept it.

Comment: @user4581301 okay, we typecast this address to pointer. But why we dereference it? By dereferencing we get value of this address, but why? Reference initialized by value of var in memory?

Comment: The "dereference" is there just because `MyCamera` or `ms_pVehiclePool` are defined as *references* an not pointers. A reference is technically a pointer (an address) but the semantics as if it was an object. `MyCamera` variable will contains the address `0xB6F028`.

Comment: @prapin so okay, by dereferencing we get value at this address 0xB6F028 and then when compiler see the reference, he is get an address of this value. yeah? And maybe we have a book about low-level programming on c++ where describe this things?

Comment: *"By dereferencing we get value of this address"* -- better to say "at" than "of". We get the value *at* that address (interpreted as an already-constructed `CCamera` object).

Comment: References don't really exist. A good way to think about references is as aliases, alternative names, to a variable. sometimes they are implemented with pointers, and sometimes the compiler can make a program that just directly manipulates the variable because it knows exactly where it is.

Comment: person below explained to me about glvalues, it's like an identifier, I understood!
@user4581301 you mentioned low-level programming. I will definitely read the literature about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By dereferencing we get a value of this address. And this value assign to reference?

You cannot assign a reference. You can only initialise a reference.

Now consider this:

```
int x = 42;
int& rx = x; // initialises rx to refer to x
```

So far so good? Let's continue.

```
int& rx = *(&x); // still initialises rx to refer to x
                 // because *(&x) is exactly the same as just x
```

No problem with that? Why `*(CCamera *)0xB6F028;` is a problem then?

When you dereference a pointer, what kind of result you get? Does `*(&x)` gets you `42`?

Not really. You get an [**glvalue**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). A glvalue determines the identity of an object. And when you initialise a reference with a glvalue, that reference starts to refer to that object. When you do most other things with a glvalue, it gets automatically converted to a prvalue, which is indeed 42 in this case. But initialising a reference is not one of those things.

So what happens when you dereference `(CCamera *)0xB6F028;`? You get a glvalue, which is the identity of an object that sits at the address `0xB6F028` and whose type is `CCamera`. And you initialise the reference with that. So the reference now refers to an object sitting at that address.

If there is indeed a `CCamera` at that address, you are good. Otherwise, an attempt to dereference that pointer is UB.

```
CPool<CVehicle, CHeli> *&CPools::ms_pVehiclePool =*(CPool<CVehicle, CHeli> **)0xB74494;
```

Same exact thing, only the type of the object is a pointer now, and the reference refers to that pointer. A pointer is just a totally regular object, so nothing terribly special is going on here.